# Multiple consecutive copy/move/delete operations will harm the hard drive? or cause defragmentation? or?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, hard-drive

I was wondering what will happen to a hard drive if we do multiple consecutive copy/move/delete operations on that drive?

For example, if I copy a chunk of data from F: drive into D: drive, and while it is running halfway, I was copying some other chunk of files from C: into D:

And while that is running, I was copying some other data from F: into D: again, Besides that I was moving some data out of D: into C:,

And while doing all that, I was deleting some files while shifting some files around in D: drive.

What will  the state of my D: drive be, compared to if I had all those operations done one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The greater the number of new files that are being written concurrently, the greater the amount of fragmentation that is likely to result (plus more needless head seeking during the operation of course).

However this normally isn't something to worry about unless you are moving Gigabytes of data - in which case it *might* be faster to do the operations consecutively and result in less fragmentation.

Comment: Yes I'm moving many Gigs of data around. Btw I'm not understanding you. Your first paragraph seems to say that concurrent move/copy/delete is going to slow things down. But your second paragraph states concurrent move/copy/delete is going to speed things up?

Comment: @Pacerier: In the 2nd para I wrote "consecutively" (one after the other, sequentially) *not* "concurrently" (all at the same time).

Comment: heys cool =D Just a quick last question, assuming I'm not interested in speed of operation, but rather the "end state", is it true that  as long as I do a disk defragmentation on `D:` after all the file moving, the "end state" of the disk would be the same regardless of whether I did consecutive or concurrent operations beforehand right? (file size of `D:` 300 GB files to move into D: 250 GB)

Comment: If it didn't, there sure would be **a lot of lawsuits**.

Comment: @surfasb I'm not sure I understand your comment..